# get value using jquery

Tags: java, jquery

i want to get value of h:outputText label using jquery,
for

```
<h:outputText id="cal_att_to_date"  
  binding="#{Attendance_Calculation.cal_att_to_date}">
     <f:convertDateTime type="date" pattern="dd-MMM-yyyy" timeZone="GMT+5:30"/>    </h:outputText>
```

Comment: Tell us the rendered HTML code of the above..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`var value = $('#cal_att_to_date').text();`

Comment: Or in case it's a text box: `$('#cal_att_to_date').val();`

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$('#cal_att_to_date').text();
```

although i would be more sure, if you displayed the rendered HTML that your code produces.