# Get a value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some options for user to choose only 1 among them, the options are in a List Item `li`, and I need to put the selected value into the textarea when the user clicks the element `a`

When user clicks on `li` save `span` value into a variable

And in the second moment when clicking on `a` the value saved in a variable must be concatenated in the textarea to the value already entered

http://jsfiddle.net/rndtatim/n3kug4ft/

The HTML fragment:

```
<pre>
    <ul> 
    <li> 
        <a class="atributo-item" data-toggle="tooltip">
         <span> Option 1 </span> 
        </a>
    </li>
     <li> 
        <a class="atributo-item" data-toggle="tooltip">
         <span> Option 2 </span>
        </a>
    </li>
     <li> 
        <a class="atributo-item" data-toggle="tooltip">
         <span> Option 3 </span> 
        </a>
    </li>
    <li> 
        <a class="atributo-item" data-toggle="tooltip">
         <span> Option 4 </span> 
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

<textarea id="consumer-message" class="fpp-field" name="Name baby" placeholder="Name baby"></textarea>

<a href="javascript:;" class="button">
  button
</a>

</pre>
```

The JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li a').on('click', function(event){
    var brasao = $(this).text();
    var imprimir = ('Option select:' + brasao);
    console.log(imprimir)
  });
});
```

Comment: what is  **attribute A** ?

Comment: please show us what you have tried and how that failed

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rndtatim/n3kug4ft/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get value using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5633682/get-value-using-jquery)

Comment: As the code currently is written in the fiddle (and now, in the question), you have one apostrophe missing on `$('ul li a )`

Answer (score 0):

I hope following code solves your problem.

I have added single quote(') at the end so changed it from `$('ul li a)` to `$('ul li a')`.

Took one global variable `var selectedOption = '';` and used it to store value.

Added `save` function in js and updated your `html` `a` tag as `<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button" onclick="save();">`.

```js
var selectedOption = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('ul li a').on('click', function(event){
    var brasao = $(this).find('span').text();
    var imprimir = ('Option select:' + brasao);
    console.log(imprimir);
    selectedOption = ' ' + brasao;
  });
});

function save() {
  $('#consumer-message').val($('#consumer-message').val() + selectedOption);
  selectedOption = '';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul> 
 <li> 
   <a class="atributo-item" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <span> Option 1 </span> 
  </a>
 </li>
  <li> 
   <a class="atributo-item" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <span> Option 2 </span>
  </a>
 </li>
  <li> 
   <a class="atributo-item" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <span> Option 3 </span> 
  </a>
 </li>
 <li> 
   <a class="atributo-item" data-toggle="tooltip">
    <span> Option 4 </span> 
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>

<textarea id="consumer-message" class="fpp-field" name="Name baby" placeholder="Name baby"></textarea>

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="button" onclick="save();">
  button
</a>
```

Comment: Hi, Mr. Karan, thanks for the help, it worked fine in jsfiddle but production is not working, look https://lune-baby-manutencao.lojaintegrada.com.br/mala-maternidade

Comment: Do you have any other alternative?